# How to determine the optimal waiting time?

Tags: algorithms

You are working at a theme park ride and your job is to clip the tickets of guests as they get on the ride. There are some restrictions:

- Only one ticket can be clipped at a time.
- The average clipped tickets per second rate should not exceed 1.
- Guests turn up at the ride every 0 ~ 2s.

How would you calculate the optimal amount of time to wait before clipping the next ticket?

---

I just made that example up to describe a rate-limiting algorithm I've been using. The way I'm calculating it is as follows:

1. Start with a pool of 100 tickets and 100 seconds.
2. Calculate a 'lower bound' as (seconds remaining / tickets remaining)

   - The minimum amount of time that is allowed to pass between clipping the next ticket in order to maintain required rate.
3. Determine the amount of time that has passed since the last clipped ticket.

   - If this amount is less than the lower bound, wait the difference.

Eg.

We're at 80 tickets left, and we have 70 seconds left to clip them, ie. we've clipped 20 tickets in the last 30 seconds. The 'lower bound' is therefore 70/80 = 0.875 seconds. So we're not allowed to clip the next ticket until at least that amount of time has passed. The next guest turns up exactly 0.5 seconds later, so we have to wait 0.375 seconds in order to even out the rate.

The problem with this solution is that I often end up with some tickets left when the time is up, which means that I could have been clipping them faster than I was.

---

**How can I determine the amount of time I need to wait before clipping another ticket?**

---

**Edit:** I've realised that my solution is actually pretty good, if you add the case that you shouldn't wait at all if the amount of tickets left is greater than the numbers of seconds to go in the current window.

Comment: I'm confused with what it means to be optimal in your problem.  There seems to be an unmentioned time limit.  Would two strategies be consider just as good as each other if they clipped the same number of tickets within the time allotted?

Comment: Yes they would. You want to clip as many tickets as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple strategy :

- if your rate is at 1 ticket/s, clip one ticket every second
- if your rate is under 1 ticket/s, clip one as soon as possible

This way, in $t$ seconds, you're always have clipped either $t$ tickets if $t$ or more people did come or $n$ ticket if $n<t$ people did come

Comment: This is very clever if you can keep track of the rate (ie. tickets per second).

Comment: @paranoid-android : It works if you can keep track of the number of ticket you've clipped (and the time since you started). If you can't track these, I'm afraid you'll be forced to clip one every second, because you can't adjust your clipping rate

Comment: I like that this method's focus is on the current ticket, whereas the solution in the question sets up the 'allowance' for the next ticket. Both seem to work but your solution appears to involve less computation. +1